# After connecting through my work's VPN, why can't I access resources using DNS?

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn

I followed the below guide which allows me to access my work's resources via VPN. Following the guide worked perfectly.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-setup-cisco-vpn-using-vpnc-ubuntu-jaunty-9-04.html

However, I can only access networked resources via IP address. Using the DNS name does not work. Why is that? What can I do to resolve (ha ha) this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you could get this to work by fully qualifying the DNS names. What this means is that at work you have a `search workdomain.com` line in your `/etc/resolv.conf` so that the local resolver will try appending that domain to any unqualified names its asked to resolve.  You can get the same effect by manually putting that line into your home  `/etc/resolv.conf`, but be aware that if you're using dhcp it might be overwritten the next time you acquire a new IP address.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 or later you should not edit /etc/resolv.conf by hand; you should configure ifup (via /etc/network/interfaces) and/or NetworkManager to put the right entries into resolv.conf (via resolvconf) when they configure interfaces/connections.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I just needed to fully qualify the DNS names.

Edit:

The instructions found in the link below can be used to permanently add a search option to resolv.conf. The user Linuturk provided the relevant information.

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-306308.html
```

> First, make sure you have internet access, and make sure resolvconf 
>   is installed on your system.
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude install resolvconf
> ```
>
> Next, let me explain the elements of resolvconf.
>
> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head is the header file for the
>   dynamic generation. Leave this alone.
>
> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base is the "meat" of the file,
>   or the middle. Define your nameservers here using this syntax:
>
> nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the ip [address] of your nameserver.
>
> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail is the ending of this file.
>   Leave this one alone too.
>
> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original is the original
>   configuration of the file. These isn't anything you have
>   to do for this file.
>
> After you have applied your changes, but before you restart
>   your network service, run this command:
>
> ```
> sudo resolvconf -u
> ```
>
> This will run the script and update your /etc/resolv.conf file.
>   This apparently should happen every time the machine boots.
>
> After that, restart your networking service with this command:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
> ```